# Nx 16 failed to resolve library path in react (js) integrated mono repo

Tags: typescript, vite, monorepo, nx-monorepo

Hi guys I'm new to NX Monorepo. I simply follow the instruction of how to create Integrated React Monorepo from NX official website.
this link right [here](https://nx.dev/react-tutorial/1-code-generation)

I exactly follow the instruction.

but i have error in `import { Banner } from '@myorg/common-ui';` .

**Cannot find module '@myorg/common-ui' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)**

this is `tsconfig.base.json` in the root of the project.

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["es2020", "dom"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@amir/common-ui": ["libs/common-ui/src/index.ts"],
      "@amir/products": ["libs/products/src/index.ts"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "tmp"]
}
```

and for each react project inside of the apps folder I have 3 `ts.config`.

```
tsconfig.app.json
===================

{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../dist/out-tsc",
    "types": ["node", "vite/client"]
  },
  "files": [
    "../../node_modules/@nx/react/typings/cssmodule.d.ts",
    "../../node_modules/@nx/react/typings/image.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/*.test.ts",
    "src/**/*.spec.tsx",
    "src/**/*.test.tsx",
    "src/**/*.spec.js",
    "src/**/*.test.js",
    "src/**/*.spec.jsx",
    "src/**/*.test.jsx"
  ],
  "include": ["src/**/*.js", "src/**/*.jsx", "src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx"]
}
```

```
tsconfig.json
=================
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "allowJs": false,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "types": ["vite/client", "vitest"]
  },
  "files": [],
  "include": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.spec.json"
    }
  ],
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json"
}
```

```
tsconfig.spec.json
=======================
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../dist/out-tsc",
    "types": ["vitest/globals", "vitest/importMeta", "vite/client", "node"]
  },
  "include": [
    "vite.config.ts",
    "src/**/*.test.ts",
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/*.test.tsx",
    "src/**/*.spec.tsx",
    "src/**/*.test.js",
    "src/**/*.spec.js",
    "src/**/*.test.jsx",
    "src/**/*.spec.jsx",
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "files": [
    "../../node_modules/@nx/react/typings/cssmodule.d.ts",
    "../../node_modules/@nx/react/typings/image.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: What does your `tsconfig.base.json` look like? It should have the alias in there.

Comment: @Alex Wayne, I updated the question as you asked.

Comment: From [@Oriol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5450345/oriol): I am having a similar problem with libraries. Not sure if it is the same case for you, but I think it is related to this: https://github.com/qmhc/vite-plugin-dts/issues/70. I did not find a valid solution, though. Did you?

Answer (score 0):

This is old but I just had a similar problem when upgrading a legacy project using `nx migrate --latest` with a react+vite library.

I did the following to correct the issue

Upgrade typescript package version to >5

Remove the following block from the library's `tsconfig.lib.json` (in your case this might be `tsconfig.json`):

```json
   "files": [
     "../../../node_modules/@nx/react/typings/cssmodule.d.ts",
     "../../../node_modules/@nx/react/typings/image.d.ts"
   ],
```

Note that the `types` array in my `tsconfig.lib.json` still has entries for `@nx/react/typings/cssmodule.d.ts` and `@nx/react/typings/image.d.ts`.

It builds fine now with a no cache build. When troubleshooting with Nx its a good practice to build without the cache so any stale entries don't end up confusing you.

e.g. in my case (I am using pnpm):

```
pnpm nx build my-lib-name-or-your-app-name --skip-nx-cache
```